# problem with callback in infinite scroll plugin

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins, callback

I'm working on a wordpress website  that utilizes David DeSandro's jQuery Masonry plugin along with Paul Irish's Infinite Scroll plugin. there is a callback  option for Infinite Scroll plugin to call Masonry. Masonry has provided 2 examples of this function:

```
$('#secondary').masonry({ appendedContent: $(this) });
```

or

```
$(this).masonry({ appendedContent: $( newElements ) });
```

But I am facing a weird problem using them. Everything works fine except it seems that every time the next posts are fetched there is a lot of empty space prepended to the very fist post. To me this space seems to be the same height as the page “1″.
this is the code:

```
 var $wall = jQuery('#secondary');
 $wall.masonry({ singleMode: true,
 itemSelector: '.box:visible'
  });
```

and I tried different functions for callback option of Infinte Scroll:

```
 $('#secondary').masonry({ appendedContent: $(this) });
```

or

```
 $(this).masonry({ appendedContent: $( newElements ) });
```

with first callback code I get empty space and with second callback code, Masonry break with callback and second page comes over the first one. script gives me an error: newelements as “undefined element”.

I want to know whats wrong that Masonry align all boxes in second page, and not first page. To me seems it append first page elements to new ones instead of appending the new elements to current ones.

but I can't find the source of problem.

Would you please help me to solve the issue.

Link to Masonry:http://github.com/desandro/masonry/raw/master/jquery.masonry.js
Infinite scroll is also on github.

Thanks!

Revision:
full infinite code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
 (window.INFSCR_jQ ? jQuery.noConflict() : jQuery)(function($){
 // Infinite Scroll jQuery+Wordpress plugin
 $('#secondary').infinitescroll({
 debug           : false,
 nextSelector    : "div.navigation a:first",
 loadingImg      : "/infinite-scroll/ajax-loader.gif",
 navSelector     : "div.navigation",
 contentSelector : "#secondary",
 itemSelector    : "div.box"
  },function(){ 
 Cufon.replace('li');
 Cufon.replace('h1');
 $('#secondary').masonry({ appendedContent: $(this) }); 
  });
 });   
 </script>
```

Comment: can you post your full infinite scroll code? also use firebug to check what is return from the request of the new pages.

Comment: Thank you for the comment. I've added the infinite scroll code to the question. Checking with firebug shows that Masonry is working and boxes from second page are aligned too, but all of them aligned with high heights! before scrolling to second page first box style which is coded by Masonry is  style="position: absolute; left: 0px; top: 0px;" after scrolling down this first box style changes to style="position: absolute; left: 380px; top: 2754px;".

Comment: The link to full infineScroll code in github is:http://github.com/paulirish/infinite-scroll

Answer (score 0):

I had the exact same problem. Switching to Isotope (a premium version of Masonry that requires a cheap license) fixed it for me. You can grab it here: http://metafizzy.co/

You might be able to solve it without upgrading by taking a look at the current issues like: https://github.com/desandro/masonry/issues#issue/44